# HBase Vs Sqoop Compatibility

Tags: hadoop, import, hbase, sqoop

I am using `HBase version 1.3.1` installed on amazon and was trying to "import" my MSSQL RDBMS database to HDFS using Sqoop ver. `1.4.6`.
Unfortunately trials were not successful. 
Is Sqoop version 1.4.6 compatible with HBase 1.3.1? Will it execute the import successfully?

Following is the command I am using to import the MSSQL DB "version 1.4.6"

```
sqoop-import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://SMSSQLDBSerevrname:Port; database=DBName;" 
--username MSSQLDBUserName --P 
--table MSSQLTableName 
--hbase-table HBaseTableName 
--column-family MyColFamilyName 
--hbase-row-key MSSQLTablePrimaryId
```

Comment: Do you want to load RDBMS data into HBase? Your command is partly right for rdbms to hbase, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272422/importing-data-from-sql-server-to-hbase

Comment: Hello Anil, Thank you for your input. I tried the Sqoop import command exactly as it was described in the post you refereed me to please see the output in my next post

Comment: however, The output was:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:222)....Your advise..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..The main issue that there was a conflict in HBase jar files and the solution was to add a directive to use Sqoop bin directory so I added the following to the structure of the command I documented above:

---

--bindir /usr/lib/sqoop/
--target-dir /usr/lib/sqoop/bin/tempd8/media
-verbose

---

Please note that 
1. The **bindir** is the directory where where the sqoop "bin" directory is located
2. **target-dir**   is where the source table data will be/is going to be  stored.
3. **-verbose** just to give more debugging information.

Also I run into memory management issues which I was able to resolve using the help of the following links:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/jpb-submitted-to-mapreduce-in-Yarn-is-stuck-while-ingesting-data/td-p/57410/page/2
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Map-Reduce-Jobs-not-starting-on-local-CDH-5-7-0-installation/td-p/39563

============To verify the sqoop import run the following command
Go to /usr/lib/hadoop/  directory
 hadoop fs -cat /usr/lib/sqoop/bin/tempd8/media/part-m-*   where the '/usr/lib/sqoop/bin/tempd8/media' is your target dir in the sqoop import command.

NOTE: Dedicated to the Engineer who was concerned about the post usefulness above