# How can I import data from mssql to hbase with sqoop (use Azure HDInsight)?

Tags: c#, azure, hbase, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to import data table from mssql to hbase with sqoop, I use C# language. I have followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/hdinsight-use-sqoop)

my code command to import data to hbase:

connectionstring:

```
connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + sqlDatabaseServerName + ";user=" + sqlDatabaseLogin + ";password=" + sqlDatabaseLoginPassword + ";database=" + sqlDatabaseDatabaseName;
```

sqoop command:

```
"import --connect " + connectionString + " --table " + tableName + " -hbase-create-table –hbase-table TestTableHBase -column-family PostID -hbase-row-key PostID -m 1"
```

I received a successful response but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you verify that Sqoop can see your SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

> **For MYSQL to HBASE:**

You can use below command to import Mysql table to HBase table:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp --username root --password cloudera --table employee --hbase-table Academp --column-family emp_id --hbase-row-key id -m 1
```

**Reference:** [How to Import Table from MySQL to HBase](https://acadgild.com/blog/how-to-import-table-from-mysql-to-hbase)

> **For SQL SERVER to HBASE**

You can use below command to import SQL server table to HBase table:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;database=db_name;username=sqoop;password=???" --hbase-create-table --hbase-table table_name_in_hbase --column-family cf_name --hbase-row-key my_ID --table tablename_in_sql_server -m 1
```

**Reference:** [importing data from sql server to hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272422/importing-data-from-sql-server-to-hbase)